# Cleaning the data- remove missing values R

Tags: r, na, missing-data

My dataframe has some "?" symbol. I try to remove them. I did change the "?" symbols into NA as follows:

```
df[df == "?"]  <- NA
df<-na.omit(df)
```

But the "?" symbols are still there. Is there any other solution to handle this problem?

Comment: Are you sure they are literal question marks? With no spaces or anything around them? Perhaps you could share a small reproducible example using `dput()` so that we can be sure we get the right class and structure of what's really there. Something like `dput(droplevels(head(df)))` is good, assuming there is a question mark in the first 6 rows.

Comment: Please make sure the ? is the only char in the field value. Try to remove leading and/or trailing whitespace from the field if there is any. http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/trimws.html

Comment: Try `grepl("\\?", df)` to select all elements that contain a question mark.